# How to ban author with on_message?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to have my bot ban someone who sends the message '$pull' and if they get 1 in randint(1,6).

```
        chamber = randint(1,6)
        if chamber == 1:
            await message.channel.send("%s got hoodbridged" % message.author)
            game_active = False
```

This is what I have but im trying to also make it ban the person if chamber == 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is Member.ban(). You can read more about it [in the docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.ban)

To use on_message:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('$pull'):
        chamber = randint(1,6)
        if chamber == 1:
            await message.channel.send("%s got hoodbridged" % message.author)
            await message.author.ban()
```

If you were to use the discord.commands.Bot class for command usage then it would look like this:

```
prefix = "$"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def pull(ctx):
    chamber = randint(1,6)
    if chamber == 1:
        await ctx.channel.send("%s got hoodbridged" % ctx.author)
        await ctx.author.ban()
```